# write sum in gams not for all member of set

Tags: debugging, sum, gams-math

i want to write sum in gams like this:
sets
s/A,B,C/
R(machinery,food)
.
.
.
 machinery_product..sum(Destination,x(machinery,A,Destination))=e=0

but program give me error because A and machinery arent set and they are member of set
how can i write this

Answer (score 0):

Set elements need to be quoted when used as index. I.e. for set `s` with element `A`: `x(s)` and `x('A')`.